# Need help in scaling this plot. Also, how many datapoints can 'pandas' library read?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scaling

I have attached 2 images. I am trying to replot image 1. I am using the same data which has been used to plot that image. I need to know how we can scale the y-axis of my plot.

my code:

```
a = pd.read_csv('SED.csv')

a.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'Frequency', y = 'Flux Density')


plt.xlim(1E+7,1E+8)
plt.ylim(1E-3,1E+4)

plt.show()
```

[I need a scaled graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6YOc.jpg)

[This what I am trying to do with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HJDk.jpg)

Comment: I have edited with my code. The screenshots was added as a url, It didnt allow me to add the image directly...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `yscale` to log

```
plt.xlim(1E+8, 1E+24)
plt.ylim(1E-12,1E+3)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xscale("log")
```